# -execdir interpretation on Linux and OSX

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, find

```
find . -iname '*.rar' -execdir ls {} +
```

this will not work under OSX Lion, yielding `ls: blabla.rar: No such file or directory` etc..

Additionally, above will work under Linux. However, it will invoke ls as many times as it find result. Tested with simple `cat $#` script.

So I see 2 problems with `-execdir`

- under Linux it will NOT combine search result as stated in manual when using `{} +`
- under OSX it will NOT change directory as stated in manual, again using `{} +`

Wanted to confirm that this is buggy and not my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about Mountain Lion, but it's a known bug in GNU findutils, apparently fixed in the 4.5 branch (check your `find --version`). See https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?19593

There is also this bug: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?29949 in find version 4.5.9, which matches the Mountain Lion symptom. Perhaps you should check both version numbers.

Comment: Sounds like same symptoms, tried with pwd originally, not changing directory. Not even sure how to check findutil version on Lion... `--version` doesn't work.

Comment: @Pablo if it doesn't respond to --version, it's not GNU find; it could well be FreeBSD find. I no longer have either a Mac or a FreeBSD box handy, so I can't help you there, but you could try Googling for FreeBSD bug reports.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux does it execute `ls` once for every file or once for every sub-directory? From `man find` (GNU findutils version 4.4.2):

> As  with  the  **`-exec`** action,  the  ‘+’  form  of **`-execdir`**  will  build  a command line to process more than one matched file, but any given invocation of command will only list files that exist in the same subdirectory.

Comment: I've just tried on Linux to put files under same sub-directory. Still I see echo $# will give me one invocation per file, nothing is combined.

Comment: `find . -iname "*.asd" -execdir test.sh {} +` is the test script. `test.sh` contains echo `$#`.